# I've recieved a message saying that I'm at risk of being question-blocked. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I have read up on what question blocking is, and I had one bad question a long time ago (-2 votes), and recently asked a question that was admittedly quite bad, and after consulting some commenters if it was proper etiquette, I deleted it. However now I have recieved this warning and I am not sure what to do.  I'm not sure if it's necessary to edit the oldest question, considering it's score and oldness. As for the most recent, I deleted it and thought it was the right thing to do in that case, so I don't know how I could edit it. Should I simply carry on and make sure not to make any bad questions, or is there something else I need to do?